# How do I implement ls -l using Scala

Tags: linux, scala

I am trying to implement `ls -l` using Scala

How do I get information such as file type, file mode bits, number of hard links, owner name, group name ?

Also if the file is a is a symbolic link it should print the link as well

Example:
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     30 Feb 17 01:03 fpu_control.h -> x86_64-linux-gnu/fpu_control.h

I don't want to use JNI to call `opendir()` and other system calls and get the data.

Answer (score 3):

A option could be to use `ls` directly:

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> val lsResult = "ls -l".!!
lsResult: String =
"total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4   user  staff   136 17 Mai  2015 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 14   user  staff   476  4 Mär 13:00 Desktop
drwx------+  4   user  staff   136 14 Feb 11:10 Documents
...
drwxr-xr-x   3...
```